# How programmatically display the Image field before Taxonomy name in Better Exposed Filters?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, media

Third day I'm looking for a solution, but I can not find an answer.
I use Taxonomy term as a filter (Better Exposed Filters) on Views.
To Taxonomy term added a field image. How programmatically display the Image field before Taxonomy name in Better Exposed Filters?
[image: Taxonomy name]

I tried modules  [taxonomy_icon](https://www.drupal.org/node/1068286#comment-4608082), [vocabulary image](https://www.drupal.org/project/vocabulary_image), [taxonomy image](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_image)
All of them do not provide an opportunity for filters Views to derive taxonomy terms in the form of "image taxonomy name".

Comment: Is your goal to replace the checkbox with an image and toggle that between an checked/unchecked version of an image?

Comment: @undersound Thank you for respond. The goal to display taxonomy image between checkbox and taxonomy name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was prompted how to do it. Thanks a lot to [xandeadx](http://dru.io/question/8048).

```
function MYMODULE_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {

foreach ($form['TAXONOMY_ELEMENT']['#options'] as $tid => &$name) {
    $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
    $name = '<img src="' . file_create_url($term->FIELD_IMAGE['und'][0]['uri']) . '" />' . $name;
  }
}
```

In my version TAXONOMY_ELEMENT = tid_1